# Copying rsync configuration

Tags: xubuntu, ssh, password, cron, rsync

I have a script running every day thanks to crontab and it works fine on a xubuntu 12.10 VM. I want to create a copy of this VM on a clean Xubuntu 16.04, and almost everything works but this script, because of a rsync problem.

```
rsync -azh --delete vbackup@perforce:/var/p4depot /tmp/p4depot
```

This line on the original server works fine, but on the clone I'm creating, the script asks me vbackup's password. It happens several times during the full script. Since I want to run it with my crontab, I don't want to enter the password every time rsync is called!
I've read it has to do with ssh configuration, but I don't know how to copy the ssh configuration for my rsync to work without modifying all the VM it's connected to.
I'm a real linux beginner, so please be exhaustive if there are path or command to run, thank you :)!

Comment: Read `man ssh-copy-id`, `man ssh_config`, `man ssh-import-id` to learn how to set up authentication for `vbackup`

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'll be able to set up authentication, but will I know how to clone the exisiting config so I don't have to modify every VM that my scripts wants to connect to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what was wrong. After setting up ssh, I was still asked a password. My python script was called with

```
sudo python3.5 myscript.py
```

The sudo was there because I had permission errors without it. I solved the permission errors, removed the sudo and the script stopped asking for my password.
In the end I still set up the ssh again, I found this thread very helpful : https://superuser.com/questions/555799/how-to-setup-rsync-without-password-with-ssh-on-unix-linux

Thanks :)